# How can my Android app get method tracing of another process/app on a phone that has enabled developer options?

Tags: android, dalvik, ddms

I would like to write an Android app (not a PC program) that has a subset features of Android Device Monitor (ADM), ie. select a process and trace its method calls, with detailed information (all the information that ADM can get, like stack trace and time), while the phone is not connected to any computer nor does it have any network access.

I've searched into `android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing*`, but it seems can only trace current process and the result can only be written into a file (I need the info in memory).

Digging its implementation, I found `dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracing*`, but it seems cannot be used by apps and I didn't find a way to specify `pid`s, neither. Looks like it's calling JNI functions, but I didn't find the implementation.

Maybe I can get the information by lower level way by using Linux perf events (`perf_event_open(2)`). But before doing that, I would like to know if such kind of feature possible to implement purely in Java (maybe by talking to some "system manager" process or "debugging server" process, or by calling some CLI tools then get its stdout)?

Answer (score 0):

These capabilities can only be accessed by the shell user (the user that adb runs as), or the root user of course. By design, a normal android application cannot access these features, because this would completely break the application sandbox that is the basis of the application security model in Android.

Comment: Does that mean, if I have root access, I can get those information? If so, how? Since the app will only be used internally by developers, I don't mind such thing.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with root access. You should take a look at the ADM source and the source of the adb daemon running on the device, in order to figure out how ADM (via the adb daemon) is performing whatever functionality it is that you want. Then, you should be able to mimic this using your own binary/shell script/etc. running on the device as root.

Comment: For example, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/908b391a9c006af569dfaff08b37f8fdd6c4da89/ddmlib/src/main/java/com/android/ddmlib/Client.java#283 might be a good place to start investigating. It looks like it sends a JDWP command to the process in order to start method tracing. So your first task will likely be to figure out how to get JDWP working on-device.

Comment: And of course, if you're able to get JDWP to work, then you have the ability to do anything a debugger typically would.  Pause the process, examine the threads/stack/heap, run code and get the result, inspect fields/variables/etc.